# TimeSynchronizer [compilation error ]

Tags: ros, timesynchronizer

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

i am getting compilation error while using `TimeSynchronizer`.

i saw [similar question](http://answers.ros.org/question/83316/trying-to-use-timesynchronizergetting-compile-error/)  , but it didnt solve.

thank you.

---

```
error: ‘TimeSynchronizer’ does not name a type
In constructor ‘Detectchange::Detectchange()’:
error: ‘timesync’ was not declared in this scope
error: expected type-specifier before ‘TimeSynchronizer’
error: expected ‘;’ before ‘TimeSynchronizer’
```

---

here is my code snippet.

---

```
class myclass
{
public:            
//some stuff            
private:
message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>* laser_scan_sub;
message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>* pose_sub;
TimeSynchronizer<sensor_msgs::LaserScanConstPtr, geometry_msgs::PoseStampedConstPtr> *timesync;
 }
```

---

```
 myclass::myclass()
 {                
 laser_scan_sub  = new message_filters::Subscriber<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>(nh_, "/ms_front_laser", 1);
 pose_sub          = new message_filters::Subscriber<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>(nh_, "/pose", 1);
 timesync = new TimeSynchronizer<sensor_msgs::LaserScanConstPtr, geometry_msgs::PoseStampedConstPtr>                         (laser_scan_sub, pose_sub, 50);
  timesync->registerCallback(boost::bind(&myclass::laserReceived, this, _1, _2));
 }
```

---

```
 void myclass::laserReceived(const sensor_msgs::LaserScanConstPtr& laser_scan, const geometry_msgs::PoseStampedConstPtr& estimate_pose)
            {
            // some stuff
            }
```

---

```
    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
      ros::init(argc, argv, "myclass");
      ros::NodeHandle nh;
    
      myclass mc;
    
      ros::spin();          
      return(0);
    }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/191755/timesynchronizer--%5Bcompilation-error-%5D/) by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3034 on 2014-09-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure you're including the proper header and using the namespace properly?

```
    #include <message_filters/time_synchronizer.h>
```

---

its problem with namespace and template arguments finally  solved by

```
timesync= new message_filters::TimeSynchronizer<sensor_msgs::LaserScan, geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>(*laser_scan_sub, *pose_sub, 50);  // solved the problem :)
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-03**:
I have header file included and tried with `using namespace message_filters;` , it didn solve the problem.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-03**:
Do you get a different error message when you add `using namespace message_filters;` ?

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-09-03**:
yes, it was from boost i think,  you can view the error [here](http://pastebin.com/vNXA3PGP)

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-03**:
This looks like the critical error message: `no known conversion for argument 2 from 'const boost::shared_ptr<const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> > > >' to 'const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::LaserScan_<std::allocator<void> > >&'`

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-03**:
That suggests that you have the template arguments to your synchronizer wrong. According to the tutorial, the template arguments to the synchronizer should be message types, not MessageConstPtrs.